# How can I set up registration and payment for an ongoing event that happens every saturday

Tags: civievent

the event happens every Saturday of the year, rain or shine with a limited participant number.

The fee is based on household so many people can be registered under one registration.  So I'd need to sign up several people to one payment.  But also have the event close once he max participation is reached

Thank you!! :)

Comment: In the future, it may be best to ask multiple questions, one per topic you'd like to see covered.  You'll get better-quality answers!

Answer (score 2):

This question has a lot of aspects. I will focus on the fact that the fee is based on the household. Does it mean that the household is your actual customer and that you are not interested in the details of the participant? And you only want to prevent that the event is overbooked? If this is the case you can use Price Fields.

[image]

- Create as part of a Price Set a Price Field set a Text/Numeric Quantity field (in my example Seats).
- Enter the participant count, make this 1 (see (1)).
- Set the price on 0.00 (this field is only used to track participants see (2)).
- Uncheck the Display Amount option.

Now in the online registration form you can enter a number in the Seats field and this will add up to the total number of participants.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the individual family members to be counted towards the event total (ie your limit is 200 people rather than 50 families) then it sounds to me like you need to use a Price Set with 2 fields

One is a 'select' field and provides the cost for the family eg $50

The second is "Text / Numeric Quantity" and has the Participant Count set to 1 (per unit(

So Mary comes along, gets charged $50 for the Family ticket, and then enters 7 in the next field, and that way 7 participants are added to the 'count' of participants.

Answer (score 2):

Others have covered have to handle the payment and max registration.  To have this event happen every weekend, you'll want to select the "Repeat" tab:

[image]